# How to do Pagination and search for table?

Tags: jquery

I am getting the data in below format 
Here In table I have  to keep three header like WoNo,WOType,WOStatusDescription

```
{WoNo: "98653210", WOType: "AWO", WOStatusDescription: "Closed"}

{WoNo: "930235", WOType: "AWO", WOStatusDescription: "Yet To Start"}

{WoNo: "987898", WOType: "AWO", WOStatusDescription: "Work In Progress"}
```

I can also get

{WoN

```
o: "98653210",WOStatusDescription: "Closed"}

{WoNo: "930235", WOStatusDescription: "Yet To Start"}

{WoNo: "987898", WOStatusDescription: "Yet To Start"}
```

Here in table I have to keep two header like WoNo,WOStatusDescription.

Here my header is not fixed,I am binding data when number of table header is not fixed

Here is my html code

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="customSearch"> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Below is my js

```
    var WOValue = [];
    // var options = '';
    var tableBody = "";
    var columns = [];

    customSearch = $("#customSearch").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "paging": true,
        "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        "aaSorting": [],
        // "dom": "Bfrtip",

        "ajax": {
            "url": P3Server + 'CustomSearch/searchdata',
            "type": 'POST',
            data: { "filterData": filterData },
            "dataSrc": function (data) {
                tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";
                for (var prop in data.LabelData[0]) {

                    if (data.LabelData[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        // Append properties such as email, fname, lname etc.
                        tableBody = tableBody + ("<th>" + prop + "</th>");
                        // Also keep a list of columns, that can be used later to get column values from the 'data' object.
                        columns.push(prop);
                    }
                }

                tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";
                var iColumns = $('#customSearch thead td').length;

                // Create the data rows.
                if (data.LabelData.length > 0) {
                    data.LabelData.forEach(function (row) {
                        // Create a new row in the table for every element in the data array.
                        tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";
                        columns.forEach(function (cell) {
                            // Cell is the property name of every column.
                            // row[cell] gives us the value of that cell.
                            tableBody = tableBody + "<td>" + row[cell] + "</td>";
                        });
                        tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";
                    });
                    $("#customSearch").append(tableBody);
                }
            }
        },
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        }


    })
```

Data is binding but pagination and search is not working.As well as I want to give link for that data where I find a wono as header in table.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to work in datatable pagination using datatable ajax

1. You will be needing function that will return your json formatted data.
2. Datatable has a powerful search function so you will not be needing a custom search function using ajax
3. Read the full documentation here. https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Sample Code Below

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
   ajax: ...,
   columns: [
       { data: 'name' },
   ]
} );
```